# resizing image with rmagick/imagemagick to be less than a specified product of its width and height

Tags: ruby, math, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm running a script that resizes images that are too large. I've used "resize_to_fit" to reduce images to a specific pixel size depending on the longer side, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with this logic instead: for any image whose *width x height* product is greater than a set value, resize the image so that the new width and height values are as large as possible while still being under that value. In other words, I don't want to arbitrarily resize the dimensions more than necessary, and I'd want to retain aspect ratio in this conversion. This may be more of a math question than a ruby one, but in any case, this is what I've tried:

```
image = Magick::Image.read(image_file)[0];
dimensions = image.columns, image.rows
resolution = dimensions[0] * dimensions[1]
if resolution > 4000000
   resolution_ratio = 4000000 / resolution.to_f
   dimension_ratio = dimensions[0].to_f * resolution_ratio
   img = img.resize_to_fit(dimension_ratio,dimension_ratio)
   img.write("#{image}")
end
```

So let's say an image has a width of 2793px and a height of 1970px. The resolution would be 5,502,210. It thus goes through the conditional statement, and as of right now, outputs a new width of 2030 and height of 1432. The product of these two is 2,906,960—which is obviously well under 4,000,000. But there are other possible *width x height* combinations whose product could be much closer to 4,000,000 pixels than 2,906,960 is. Is there a way of determining that information, and then resizing it accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly calculate the `ratio`, which is a square root from your desired dimension divided by (`row` multiplied by `col`):

```
row, col = [2793, 1970]
ratio = Math.sqrt(4_000_000.0 / (row * col))
[row, col].map &ratio.method(:*)
#⇒ [
#  [0] 2381.400006266842,
#  [1] 1679.6842149465374
#]
[row, col].map(&ratio.method(:*)).reduce(:*)
#∞ 3999999.9999999995
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! This is absolutely perfect. A dumb math question though: what is the logic behind taking the square root of that first ratio? Just trying to make sure I get the concept there.

Comment: Both `col` and `row` should be normalized by `ratio`, what gives `ratio` in the denominator _squared_. Hence the retrieve it the square root is required. It’s a basic arithmetic proportion.